# Group by in mongoDB gives strange result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents like this below:

```
{
    "IMDBURL":"http:\/\/us.imdb.com\/M\/title-      exact?Schrei%20aus%20Stein%20(1991)",
    "release_date":"08-Mar-1996",
    "ratings":[{"user_id":916,"rating":3,"timestamp":"880845755"}], 
    "genre":["Drama","Thriller"],
    "video":"","title":"Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)"
}
```

and I trying to show the titles of the movies with the number of genres they belong.

So far I am doing this

```
db.bigdata.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$genre"},
    {$group: {_id:"$title",genres:  {$sum:"$genre"}}}
)
```

I receive this response

```
 {"_id" : "Sunchaser, The (1996)", "genres" : 0 }
 { "_id" : "Kika (1993)", "genres" : 0 }
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Results are correct. What is your expected response?

Comment: "genre" is a string that is why you are getting that result. If you need the number of genres, you should use the `$size` operator

Comment: Might be because of $sum

Comment: What is your expected result using the document you've shown us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mongodb [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) documentation:

```
{ $sum : <field> }  Numeric                     Sum of Values
{ $sum : <field> }  Numeric and Non-Numeric     Sum of Numeric Values
{ $sum : <field> }  Non-Numeric or Non-Existent 0
```

As you can see, third case clearly states - sum of non-numeric fields will give you `0` as result. If you want to get collection of all genres back, then you should use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/). If you want to get count of genres, you should use

```
{$group: {_id:"$title", genres: {$sum:1}}}
```

And there is no need to unwind and group for that (unless you have duplicated genres) - simple $size will do the same in projection operator.

Comment: Yeah I am new to mongo and I didn't notice that. I believe that I need to count the number of types of genres each movie belongs I have to unwind. Otherwise with your query it will always give the genre field equal to one , which is normal as every document has a genre field.

Comment: @Akis why? $size will return number of genres

Comment: Yeah the size do the job but not the sum. Thank you a lot